# Lightroom shows error when exporting

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5, export

Some weeks ago, Lightroom 5 started to show an error message every time I export a photo (from jpeg or DNG to any format, single image or batch, no difference).

[image: Lightroom Error Message]

(From German: "Attention, Export not possible: an internal error has occured")

The exported pictures are all there and fine, nothing is missing there. But the same error keeps coming up every time, no matter what settings I change in the export dialog.

Did anybody maybe have a similar issue?

Comment: do you have a custom action defined at the bottom of your export dialog?

Comment: No, no custom Action.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? that error looks there is an issue with lightroom communicating with the OS to create the exported file. <win key>+R, type `cmd`, then type `ver`, and <enter>

Comment: Disable plugins and try again. The dialog says it is failing to execute a program outside of Lightroom which can only be a plugin AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comments I was able to solve the problem:

For some reason in the export dialog the "custom action" field was completely blank, instead of showing "no action". Changing this made the error message dissappear!

What it looked like:
[image]

What it should look like:
[image]